# pdfTex error (\pdfximage)! not allowed in DVI mode

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I have a PNG file in the figure also graphicx package has been added. Still I get this error!

These are the packages/settings I am using:

```latex
\usepackage{myphdthesis}
\input epsf
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
  multi-part-units = single,}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Can someone please help?

N.B.: The same code was successfully run few months ago in another machine with Windows 7 in TeXnic Center. Now I installed latex Miktex and TeXnic center in a Windows 10 environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From your error message it looks like you are running `pdftex`. You could try running `pdflatex` (LaTeX=>PDF) instead, see for example the screenshot at https://www.dataonlygreater.com/assets/images/TeXnicCenter_compile.png.

Comment: To me, it rather seems that the pdfTeX engine (maybe via the `pdflatex.exe` executable) is run in DVI mode while trying to include a PDF image, which isn't supported. Isn't the `pdflatex.exe` program called with `-output-format dvi` or something like that? In this case, try removing these options, or choose “generate PDF” instead of “generate DVI”, whatever the precise wording is in TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Thanks. I tried pdflatex, but seems like it's having problem to generate the pdf file. I already have the latest GS installed.

Comment: EPSf about 30 years ago in a century long past was for use of EPS with dvips The orig­i­nal (and now ob­so­les­cent) graph­ics in­clu­sion macros for use with dvips, still widely used by Plain TeX users (in par­tic­u­lar) thus is current BUT. similarly {epstopdf} is considered redundant you are trying to force both to co-exist with graphicx png handlers. refresh your review of which one to use and discard the others